# Less devices suported after changes on Google Play

Tags: android

I have some apps on Google Play.

Weeks ago Google made some changes on Google Play, after that changes I updated one of my apps and I got a messages that told me something about changes in default devices suported, now in 2 tabs where I had installed the app, the app is not supported.

For more one year I made changes in the app and I never had problems. Latest changes in the app was modifying only a database. No changes in permissions, no changes in SDK, no changes in hardware suport.

Several users reported me that they could not update the app.

### This is part of the Manifest file

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

minSdkVersion 4 for suport Android 1.6

My devices where now the app is not compatible:
Asus Transformer TF300 - Android 4.2.1
Acer Iconia A500 - Android 4.0.3

Devices where is compatible:
HTC Dream - Android 1.6
Sony Xperia Sola - Android 4.0.4

In the list of supported devices on Google Play Asus TF300 and Iconia A500 are checked

What is the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you used Target sdk version?

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="17"/> //android 4.2
```

So it supports from min sdk version ie android 1.5 to maximum android sdk version 4.2

Comment: android:targetSdkVersion="17" This part is not in my manifest  but in previous version either. for some reason it is missing in this project but in my other apps I have that part. I will check it. Thanks

Comment: I added the line mentioned and now it works, I defined also again the SDK with which I compiled to use API version 8. Now I can see again the app in my devices and I can update it Thank you :D